# what is causing ord() to not print out the unicode?

Tags: python, string, unicode, ord

its just printing back the letters currently and i'm wondering how to get it to print unicode.

```
def encoder():

    plain=input('Enter a word: ')

    for i in plain:
        ord(i)
        print(i, end='')
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything with the result of`ord(i)`; you just call it and throw the value away.  You need to assign it to something, or print it:

```
print(ord(i), end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

Integers and strings are immutable and `ord()` won't change `i` in-place for you. You need to *assign* the resulting value of `ord()` back to `i`:

```
i = ord(i)
```

Or just print the output of the function instead of `i`:

```
for i in plain:
    print(ord(i), end='')
```

This will print the *decimal* value of the codepoint. If you wanted hexadecimal output, you'd need to format the integer return value of `ord()` as such, probably with some spaces in between:

```
for i in plain:
    print(format(ord(i), 'x'), end=' ')
```

This uses the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to format an integer as a lower-cased hexadecimal number by usitng the `x` format specification.

Now you get:

```
>>> plain = 'Hello world!'
>>> for i in plain:
...     print(format(ord(i), 'x'), end=' ')
... 
48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21
```